# How to import Macapi Core foundation and other Macapi namespaces in Fire Monkey HD app?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to use Macapi Core foundation and other Macapi namespaces with in Fire monkey HD application.How can I import them.I am trying to include it with in uses clause under interface section but it shows **Can not resolve unit name Macapi.CoreFoundation**.please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my problem.I have to first add OSX plateform under target platform section and select OSX platform as target platform then it will resolve Macapi namespaces.